# XML Application String cant be displayed

Tags: javascript, html, xml

The Sting "Fahrzeugnummer" in "Fahrten: All other strings in "Fahrten" are working fine. Just "Fahrzeugnummer" can't be displayed.

> Table

```
<table style="width:100%" id="fahrten-tabelle"></table>
```

> Script

```
<script>
    function loadXMLDoc() {
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                myFunction(this);
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "https://start.vag.de/dm/api/v1/fahrten.xml/Bus?timespan=100", true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }

    function myFunction(xml) {
        var i;
        var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
        var table = "<tr><th>Fahrzeugnummer</th><th>Linie</th></tr>";
        var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Fahrt");
        for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {

            //Problem:
            var fznr = x[i].getElementsByTagName("Fahrzeugnummer")[0] ? x[i].getElementsByTagName("Fahrzeugnummer")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue : "";

            table += "<tr><td>" +
                //Problem:
                fznr +
                "</td><td>" +
                x[i].getElementsByTagName("Linienname")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
                "</td></tr>";
        }
        document.getElementById("fahrten-tabelle").innerHTML = table;
    }
</script>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the value use innerHTML and not nodeValue.

```
 function myFunction(xml) {
    var i;
    var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
    var table = "<tr><th>Fahrzeugnummer</th><th>Linie</th></tr>";
    var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Fahrt");
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        table += "<tr><td>" + x[i].childNodes[0].innerHTML + "</td><td>" + x[i].childNodes[1].innerHTML + "</td></tr>";
    }
    document.getElementById("fahrten-tabelle").innerHTML = table;
}
```

here's a demo

```js
    function loadXMLDoc() {
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                myFunction(this);
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "https://start.vag.de/dm/api/v1/fahrten.xml/Bus?timespan=100", true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }

    function myFunction(xml) {
    var i;
    var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
    var table = "<tr><th>Fahrzeugnummer</th><th>Linie</th></tr>";
    var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Fahrt");
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        table += "<tr><td>" + x[i].childNodes[0].innerHTML + "</td><td>" + x[i].childNodes[1].innerHTML + "</td></tr>";
    }
    document.getElementById("fahrten-tabelle").innerHTML = table;
}
```

```html
<body onload="loadXMLDoc()">
<table style="width:100%" id="fahrten-tabelle"></table>
</body>
```

Comment: that doesnt change anything

Comment: I guess you are doing something wrong, works for me.

Comment: Yes, i did something wrong. Now it works. Thank you very much!